# Delete a comment by Graph API from fb:comments posted by an user?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0, xfbml

I have a comment box in an application ().

With Graph Api I can get all new comments from this comment box .

My issue is that:
is it possible to remove a comment posted by an user with Graph API?

With Graph APi Explorer, i have tried to call "DELETE https://graph.facebook.com/" with an user access token but I have got a bad answer:

```
{
  error: {
    type: "OAuthException",
    message: "(#200) Users can only delete their own comments",
  },
}
```

I have also test with the app access token give to me by Facebook in developper app page, but with no success. This app access token have no permissions.

Have you an idea please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It is currently not possible to remove comments from the comments box via the Graph API. You can moderate comments to hide/boost a comment or ban a user from the Developer App (http://developers.facebook.com/apps) or directly from the comments box (provided the appropriate open graph meta tags are added).

Comment: Cat, I have found the solution so it's possible ;)
You can delete a comment of an user with the user's access token ;).

Comment: You can remove comments from the user's wall, but I don't believe the Graph API lets you remove a comment from the comments box directly.

Comment: I can do that Cat Lee.
I get user's access token and my app remove user's comments in comment box, so it's possible :).